# Issue during react-native run-ios

Tags: react-native

React-native run iOS, error unrecognised command run iOS
Info Run "react-native --help" to see a list of all available commands.
These error occur many time 
I haven't answer

Comment: Are you sure react-native command is in your environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the right command

```
react-native run-ios
```

Instead

```
React-native run iOS
```